# Rest WS Filter like a Servlet Filter?

Tags: rest, servlets, glassfish, jersey

I am running Jersey on Glassfish.  How can I run every web service request through a filter?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21455_01/common/tutorials/ws_filter.html

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing its called a ContainerRequestFilter

```
      com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
```